# Replace extensions in List<String>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I have the following list of strings where I would like to remove/replace the last part (i.e. “.mp4\n”) of the string with String.Empty.

```
List<String> _response
[0] ---- “test.mp4\n”
[1] ---- “test2.mov\n”
[3] ---- “test3.mp4\n”
[4] ---- “test3.mp3\n”
etc.
```

How can I remove the extensions in a smart and simple way? I'm using .NET 4.0 and I'm new to C# and .NET.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx) Method like:

```
var newList = _response.Select(r=> Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(r.Trim())).ToList();
```

Use [`string.Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) if your string ends with `\n`

Or Shorter form (if the file name doesn't contain '\n`):

```
var newList = _response.Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast reply Habib !! This works perfect for me... exactly what I was looking for :-)